# How to write scenario outline to capture list of object in a single argument?

Tags: cucumber, cucumber-jvm, gherkin

When writing cucumber scenario outline test cases, sometimes i have requirement that i need one of the placeholder to hold a list of data instead of one. See below pseudo example:

```
Scenario Outline: example
Given I have <input_1> 
When I choose <input_2>
Then I should receive <result_list>  //instead of a single result

Examples:
| input_1        | input_2        | result                 |
| input_1_case_1 | input_2_case_1 | result_1_case_1_part_1 |
|                |                | result_1_case_1_part_2 |
|                |                | result_1_case_1_part_3 |
```

In the above example, my "result" need to capture a list of object for each single input_1 and input_2 parameter. But with the above writing, cucumber will not compile the last statement to something like:

```
@Then("....")
public void i_should_receive(Datatable or list of object) throws Throwable {
    // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
    throw new PendingException();
}
```

How can write my cucumber script to achieve what i want?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Scenario Outline: example
Given I have <input_1> 
When I choose <input_2>
Then I should receive <result_list>  //instead of a single result

Examples:
| input_1        | input_2        | result                                                                
| input_1_case_1 | input_2_case_1 | result_1_case_1_part_1,result_1_case_1_part_2,result_1_case_1_part_3 |
```

Then in your step definition

```
@Then("....")
public void i_should_receive(String result) throws Throwable {
    List<String> items = Arrays.asList(str.split("\\s*,\\s*"));
}
```

Comment: If someone else might create/edit the list in feature file throw a trim() in there to remove leading or trailing white spaces.

Comment: Cool.It's a lot better than having each part of result as a separate column.

Answer (score 0):

I've been able to set a list of values in a cucumber example, this way:

```
Scenario Outline: The role already exists in the system, with the specified permissions
    Given the user admin is logged in
    And the role ADMIN with permissions <permissions> to be created
    When a call to SecurityService is performed to create system roles
    Then http status code 200 is returned
    Examples:
      |permissions                                       |
      |REGISTER_ACCOUNT,REVOKE_TOKENS,GET_ROLES,SET_ROLES|
```

And the concrete method:

```
 @And("^the role ([^\"]*) with permissions ([^\"]*) to be created$")
 public void theRoleWithPermissionsToBeCreated(String roleCode, List<String> permissions) {
```

for me, this works like a charm and I receive a list of Strings directly, without the need to parse a string value